# multiple boolean parameters in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a case where I need to use checkboxes parameters along with string parameter in a declarative pipeline in jenkins , each checkbox represent url

```
parameters {

  booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'https://test1.com', description: 'Non-Prod' )

  booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'https://test2.com', description: 'Non-Prod'

  booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'https://test3.com', description: 'Prod')

  string(name: 'user', defaultValue: '')

}
```

I want to iterate over only the checkboxes with true value ( checked ) and also I need to do certain steps based on the description of the boolean parameter

Comment: It would probably be much easier to refactor them into a single `list` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by doing the below :

```
stages {
stage('Create Account') {
steps {
script {
params.keySet().each {
if ( params."${it}" && it.matches("https(.*)")) {
--- }
```